# как передать значение переменной в PHP из JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

есть index.html
...

```
 <script>

 var toggle_w=-1;

 </script>
<input id="tw" type="button" action="upload.php" onclick="toggle_w=tw(toggle_w)" name="toggle_w" method="post" value="Накладывать водяной знак">    

    <form id="upload" method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <div id="drop">
                        Перетащить сюда


                    <input type="file" name="upl" multiple />
                </div>

            </form>
```

..

upload.php загружает брошенные в div файлы 
я хочу добавить кнопку, которая будет в этот upload.php передавать параметр tw=1 или tw=-1 без перезагрузки страницы index.html
по умолчанию tw=1
при кликах по кнопке tw меняется +1 -1 +1 -1

```
<script>
var tw = function(tw) {
    tw = tw*(-1);


        $.ajax({
          method: "POST", 
          url: "upload.php", 
          data: { 
            tw: tw;
          },
        })

    return tw;
}
</script>
```

a в upload.php пытаюсь получить переменную

```
$toggle_w = $_POST['tw'];
```

как правильно отправить переменную из index.html и как её получить в upload.php?

Comment: `tw: tw,` - Тут так надо, а не точку с запятой. Возможно, у Вас в консоли ошибки сыпет - проверьте. А так, по логике вроде всё правильно.

Comment: я пробовал с ; , и без всего
моя переменная не доходит до php

Comment: в консоли что пишет?

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю, что Функция tw инвертирует значение toggle_w, а затем выполняет пост запрос с передачей нового значения.

Ну так вот, полагаю проблема в том, что tw и upl не приходят в upload.php одновременно. Если я прав, то обратите внимание, что отправка tw происходит при клике по кнопке, а отправка upl должна произойти на форме (Только не вижу кнопки "Отправить").
Попробуйте навесить обработчик onsubmit на форму, который:

1. Прервёт перезагрузку страницы event.preventDefault
2. Сформирует и отправит запрос тем же $.ajax, прикрепив и tw, и upl.

P.S.: Как заметил [Vladimir Gonchar](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/300171/vladimir-gonchar), точка с запятой после свойства обьекта и вправду лишняя.

Comment: в div пользователь перетаскивает файлы и они падают в папку, мне не нужна там отправить
я хочу предать один единственный параметр в upload.php, он логической структуры.
я ставил запятую, точку с запятой и убирал всё, не работает
в моей структуре, index.html вызывает upload.php, может ли upload.php динамически принимать переменные в принципе? или только при каждом новом вызове?

Comment: @petrovich ну, смотри, чтобы узнать отправились ли параметры - открой в Chrome инструменты разработчика  (клавиша F12), вкладку Network. Соверши отправку, просмотри заголовки и параметры запроса. Если параметр там есть - значит он улетает и как-то его в твоём PHP-скрипте можно получить

Comment: А дальше станет понятно, читать тебе документацию по JQuery или PHP:)

Comment: не улетает, я сразу все переменные в логи пишу

Comment: `<script>
 
   $( "button" ).click(function(){ // задаем функцию при нажатиии на элемент <button>
     
  $.ajax({
       type: post, // метод HTTP, используемый для запроса
       url: upload.php, // строка, содержащая URL адрес, на который отправляется запрос
       data: { // данные, которые будут отправлены на сервер
         toggle_w: toggle_w,
       },
 })
   });
 
  </script>`
@Жека может не так шлю?

Comment: То есть сам запрос не отсылается, или он отсылается, но без аргумента?

Comment: ничего не отсылается

Comment: То есть сам запрос не уходит? Тогда нужно подумать о том, срабатывает ли Ваш обработчик клика кнопки. Возможно он неверно привязан и не вызывается. Возможно содержит ошибку и тихо(или не очень, посмотрите в консоль при клике) вылетает.

Comment: Ошибочно сразу диагностировать ошибку в Вашем PHP-скрипте не убедившись, что запрос улетает со всеми данными.

Comment: я хочу кликнуть на кнопку на index.html без перезагрузки и обновления index.html - отправить 1 логическую переменную в upload.php
есть способ это сделать?

Comment: Конечно! Я если честно не знаю как на JQuery, но зато знаю как сделать это на Axios.js и просто через XmlHttpRequest.
Но в твоём случае сперва узнай, срабатывает ли событие? Для этого размести в обработчике брейкпоинт, или хотя бы console.log('click') напиши. Если событие срабатывает - проблема с отправкой данных, если не срабатывает - проблема с привязкой обработчика

Comment: Знаете, ещё совсем недавно я тоже имел привычку засыпаться и расслабляться, когда какую-то задачу не мог решить. Но сейчас ситуация требует от меня быстрого выхлопа, а значит я должен сделать всё возможное для решение задачи. Первое, что Вы должны сделать - это самостоятельно локализовать задачу в настолько узком месте, насколько только возможно. А уже после разбирайте кусок, ищите ошибки и пишите вопросы на StackOverflow.

Comment: в консоли клики отображаются, в network наблюдаю как в upload.php передаётся моя переменная по задуманному алгоритму, но upload ее не принимает.

Comment: Ну так может обновишь свой вопрос и покажешь скрин с твоим параметром в запросе?

Comment: Если переменная отправляется, а в PHP-скрипте ты её не получаешь, тогда разверни обьект аргументов и поищи её!

Comment: что в данном случае объект аргументов?

Comment: У меня было такое, что параметры, когда ожидал получить из напрямую, оборачивались в обьект params или data. Распечатай свой объект и ищи! Я не вижу твой проект

Comment: решил вопрос другой структурной последовательностью. передать переменную в конкретном случае, я так и не смог. в других случаях переменные передаются нормально.

Comment: Тогда ответь на свой вопрос, посмотрим что у тебя было и как ты это решил

Comment: Я использую форму загрузки файлов, брошенных в div, на php. Мне непонятно, но видимо этот скрипт php может принимать только определенные переменные. на мои переменные он отвечал "error" я не знаю, как можно запретить получать переменные php файлу, по-этому, не знаю куда копать.я сделал другой php, который сам меняет то, что мне нужно в этом проблемном файле.